# Use Execution API from App script to App script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Execution api in app script to call another app script, but I see nowhere some examples to do that.
I've developed the app script api, but I don't know how to make the call in app script.
I need too to have an example to implement the oauth in this script to be able to access the app script api.

Someone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: That seems like overkill. Why not just bundle the scripts you want to call as a library and have you other script call them that way? Its much easier.

Comment: Can't you use the same oAuth token for another execution API script call? Just make sure first both scripts have same scopes.

Comment: I have the token but I don't know how to handle the authentication process in the client script ...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) which is a library for Google Apps Script that provides the ability to create and authorize OAuth2 tokens as well as refresh them when they expire. This library uses Apps Script's new [`StateTokenBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder) and `/usercallback` endpoint to handle the redirects.